# removeFromSuperview after viewController transition is complete.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following method inside a `subview`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.delegate performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueAdicionarRefeicaoSearch" sender:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.arrayLabels[indexPath.row]]];
    // Remove from Superview 
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

What happens with this code is that the view gets removed before the `performSegue` animation completes, and the visual effect is not so good.

I know one solution is to remove the view like this:

`[self.view performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25f];`

But I think that's too mechanic to choose the `TimeInterval`for the animation. Is there something different I can use?

I could also get the `subview`index in the navigation stack and remove it when I get to `viewDidAppear`of the next view. But I think this would be even more complicated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to remove it? Why not `viewDidDisappear:`?

Comment: This is a `subview` that occupies half of my screen on top of another `view`. After going to another view and coming back, this `subview`is still there. That's why I think I need to remove. Don't I? Or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Can't tell without knowing what it is a subview of. Should it be there still based on requirements? If not then remove it...

Comment: Imagine VC1, button press opens this `subview` in question, which open some basic cells for selections and moving to VC3. That's pretty much it, when user gets back to VC1 from VC3, I don't want this subview to be there.

Comment: I guess `[self.view removeFromSuperView]` in `viewDidDisappear`will be fine.

Comment: Fair enough. Out of interest, why is it `self.view`? Why not `self.optionsView` or something?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point. It is a `tableViewController` with .h and .m files that I use to retrieve some labels from network. And I make it a `subview`of another `tableViewController`. I call it like: `[self addChildViewController:myVC];`
    `[self.view addSubview:myVC.tableView];` after setting frame. Please let me know if this is unnecessary or if there's a simpler way. Thanks.

Comment: `self.view removeFromSuperview` is in the implementation of `subview`. Thanks.

Comment: Not unnecessary, it's just that it is really the responsibility of the superview controller to remove the child and subview (the child view controller shouldn't remove its own view).

Answer (score 2):

Depending what the view is or why you need to remove it, one option would be to call it in `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` I don't know why you would need to remove the view from the controller, but this method definitely is called after the animation.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self.whateverView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Edit:**
Based on your response, you could also do it in viewWillAppear: since it sounds like you don't want it only when you return back to your viewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear];

    [self.whateverView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: This is a `subview` that occupies half of my screen on top of another `view`. After going to another view and coming back, this `subview`is still there. That's why I think I need to remove. Don't I? Or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, then it wouldn't be self.view per say, but should be self.mycustomview or whatever it's called. You don't want to remove the viewControllers view